# An accelerated charge produces an electromagnetic wave. Is light an electromagnetic wave despite not having charged particles?

Tags: visible-light

Light is an electromagnetic radiation contrary to the law of electromagnetism that states that: an accelerated charge produce electromagnetic wave. Please explain.

Comment: In quantum electrodynamics, photons are the 'mediators' of force between charged particles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is light called an 'electromagnetic wave' if it's neither electric nor magnetic?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41680/)

Comment: Where is the contradiction? Light is light and charged particles are charged particles. Accelerate them in just the right way and they make light. See Bremsstrahlung, synchrotron radiation, wiggler and undulator.

Answer (score 3):

> Light is an electromagnetic radiation

correct

> contrary to the law of electromagnetism that states that: an accelerated charge produce electromagnetic wave.

No it is not contrary, the electromagnetic wave produced according to [Maxwell's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) travels with the speed of light and leaves the charged source.

> Is light an electromagnetic wave despite not having charged particles?

All electromagnetic waves originated at the field of a charged particle , either through acceleration or through excitation of atoms and emission of photons, photons being the quanta that build up electromagnetic waves. The light from the sun, for example originated in the electric and magnetic fields of the sun and the plasma of its photosphere, where electrons and nuclei are separated and continue interacting and loosing energy by emitting photons in the field of each other.