# Does light have magnetic poles?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

If visible light is electromagnetic field of certain wavelength does it form closed loops?

Comment: I like this question. Thinking outside the box

Comment: There is no electric current to form a closed loop, no moving charge.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19632/

Answer (score 1):

As far as we know, there are no magnetic monopoles, in light or anywhere else. This is what $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B}=0$, which is one of Maxwell’s equations, says. Thus magnetic field lines have nowhere to “end”. They form closed loops or extend to infinity.

Comment: I think the question was more about magnetic dipoles.